# Installing D365 SDK Tools Error with PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, microsoft-dynamics

I have run this script numerous times on many machines without issue.  I am getting the following on a new PC.

Script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/download-tools-nuget

Issue:

[image: Script Error]

Comment: As per the error, does the ```C:\Windows\System32\tools``` directory exist?

Comment: The main directory does, but this script normally creates the Tools folder in the directory.  If I manually create it and run the script, it deletes the Tools folder.

Comment: Potentially more of a permissions issue. What user does it run as? Is there anything different about that computer?

Comment: Running PS as Admin users.  Nothing, newer Lenovo (1 year old).